# Same page template but ackground image doesn't show

Tags: css, images

I have installed new theme for Wolf CMS [here](http://www.steve.doig.com.au/web-site-applications.html).

[This](http://wolfcms.office-web.net/extensions/themes/bluebusiness.html) is a demo of the template.

Why does the content background image show on the demo but not on my site?  The HTML and CSS is the same, and the image exists on my server.

The background image *does* show on my home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

The pages in question had a sidebar in Wolf CMS, while the working pages did not.

I removed the sidebar.